# wordpress attachment not grabbing the correct images

Tags: php, wordpress, attachment

I'm trying to get the list of the images attach in a post to build a slider, but it's happen that the images that has being grab are the first two images in the media library and not the images add it to the post

**content-gallery.php**

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class( 'advanceplr-format-gallery' ); ?>>
<header class="entry-header text-center">

    <?php if( advanceplr_get_attachment() ):
        $attachments = advanceplr_get_attachment(7);
        var_dump($attachments);
    ?>

    <div id="post-gallery-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

            <?php
                $i = 0;
                foreach( $attachments as $attachment ):
                $active = ( $i == 0 ? ' active' : '' );
            ?>

            <div class="item<?php echo $active; ?> background-image standard-featured" style="background-image: url( <?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment->ID ); ?> );"></div>

            <?php $i++; endforeach; ?>

        </div><!-- .carousel-inner -->

            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#post-gallery-<?php the_ID(); ?>" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#post-gallery-<?php the_ID(); ?>" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>

    </div><!-- .carousel -->

        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title"><a href="'. esc_url( get_permalink() ) .'" rel="bookmark">', '</a></h1>'); ?>

        <div class="entry-meta">
            <?php echo advanceplr_posted_meta(); ?>
        </div>

</header>

<div class="entry-content">

    <div class="entry-excerpt">
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="button-container text-center">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="btn btn-advanceplr"><?php _e( 'Read More' ); ?></a>
    </div>

</div><!-- .entry-content -->

<footer class="entry-footer">
    <?php echo advanceplr_posted_footer(); ?>
</footer>
```

**theme-support.php**

```
function advanceplr_get_attachment( $num = 1 ){

$output = '';
if( has_post_thumbnail() && $num == 1 ): 
    $output = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id( get_the_ID() ) );
else:
    $attachments = get_posts( array( 
        'post_type' => 'attachment',
        'posts_per_page' => $num,
        'post_parent' => get_the_ID()
    ) );
    if( $attachments && $num == 1 ):
        foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ):
            $output = wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment->ID );
        endforeach;
    elseif( $attachments && $num > 1 ):
        $output = $attachments;
    endif;

    wp_reset_postdata();

endif;

return $output; }
```

I also have a post format for the image that use the same code and it working,

**content-image.php**

```
<article id="post-<?php  the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class( 'advanceplr-format-image' ); ?> >

    <header class="entry-header text-center background-image" style="background-image: url(<?php echo advanceplr_get_attachment(); ?>);">


        <?php the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title"><a href="'. esc_url( get_permalink() ) .'" rel="bookmark">', '</a></h1>' ); ?>

        <div class="entry-meta">
            <?php echo advanceplr_posted_meta(); ?>
        </div>

        <div class="entry-excerpt image-caption">
            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
        </div>

    </header>

<footer class="entry-footer">
    <?php echo advanceplr_posted_footer(); ?>
</footer>
```